# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns false after setting cookie and validating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a problem with MVC4 user authorization.

`System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser` returns `true`.
Then it gets to `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` and I see a cookie in my browser.
Then `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` still evaluates to `false` for some reason.
`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is still false after a redirect and stays `false`.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: @corywest Post the code where you are using SetAuthCookie

Comment: @corywest What does your web.config look like? Did you specify forms authentication there?

Comment: @Dismissile The authentication was working a week ago. I do not know what I did to break it. The code in the block has not changed since then.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` won't be set to true until the next request after calling `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()`.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx

> The SetAuthCookie method adds a forms-authentication ticket to either
>   the cookies collection, or to the URL if CookiesSupported is false.
>   The forms-authentication ticket supplies forms-authentication
>   information to the next request made by the browser.

Comment: i found this out the hard way. If you check right after authenticating, within same code block, no dice

Comment: User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is still false after redirecting the user and it stays false.

Comment: Can you verify that `model.UserName` is not null or empty when you call `SetAuthCookie`?

Comment: i also have the same issue. have the web config setting as well as correct code but it is always false

Answer (score 21):

Check your webconfig, you have to enable forms authentication:

Add following snippet inside

```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="3600" />
    </authentication>
```

Comment out if it is in your webconfig:

```
<!--<modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>-->
```

Now you can check

WebSecurity.CurrentUserName, WebSecurity.CurrentUserId and , WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated flags;

Comment: You saved me @Nalan M

Comment: I was missing removing <modules> part, thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah I commented just the <remove> tag because Glimpse uses that <modules> section as well, but this definitely solved my issue!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It requires an additional roundtrip (RedirectToAction), but this accomplished what I wanted. Also I am not using a strongly typed model in this sample but it demonstrates the idea. The code checks if the user is authenticated and if not sets the cookie, then redirects to itself. The second time it's called IsAuthenticated is true and the View is returned. Just make sure your form inputs are named userName and password.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password, string returnUrl)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return View(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        if (System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { userName = userName, password = password, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                //return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    }
}

// If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
return View(model);
}
```