# Asp.net Identity : User.Identity.GetUserId() is always null and User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is alway false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

See my code below:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        string UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId(); 
        return RedirectToAction("ClientDetails","Home");
    case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
        return View("Lockout");
    case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
        return RedirectToAction("SendCode", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
    case SignInStatus.Failure:
    default:
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View(model);
}
```

The `UserId` is always `null` and `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is always `false`. But I can view the View `ClientDetails` which requires authentication.

Comment: Do you have your site setup for Windows auth?

Comment: @Daniel Sanchez  No.   <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

Comment: Read this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810496/forms-authentication-understanding-context-user-identity

Please set cookies first

Comment: I was trying to do the exact same thing. Nitin is probably correct, but this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508495/user-identity-isauthenticated-returns-false-after-setting-cookie-and-validating?rq=1 clarified it more for me in saying "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated won't be set to true until the next request after calling FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()"
(In case someone else comes along with the same issue.)

Comment: I have this same problem. I copied the boilerplate code and changed very little. When I run the boilerplate Login action everything works as predicted. When I try my copied action I get what happens to OP.

Comment: see variable "scope". i believe it's a scope issue.

Answer (score 17):

I assume your example is the code from your AccountController.Login() method. I had the same problem as you but discovered that the User object won't be populated until the next request.  Try this approach:

```
case SignInStatus.Success:
    return RedirectToAction("DoWork", "Account");


public async Task<ActionResult> DoWork()
{
    //this works
    string UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    //return to View or Redirect again
}
```

Answer (score 13):

For the "The UserId is always null" part of the question, you can look up the user by the model.UserName:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
switch (result)
{
    case SignInStatus.Success:
        ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindByName(model.UserName);
        string UserId = user.Id;
        // UserId is now populated
        return RedirectToAction("ClientDetails","Home");
```

etc. Not sure if you wanted User.Identity.IsAuthenticated true or whether that was an observation - this doesn't change that part.

Answer (score 0):

Worked with me after tagging the method with    [Authorize] 
attribute and sending the access-token in the authorize header, it seems that the access-token is needed to recognize the user