# Unable to retrieve userID

Tags: c#, authentication

I tried all different ways but still couldn't not retrieve the current userID after a successful login. No errors returned.

Below is the code out of the box:

```
        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
        var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                Session["userID"] = User.Identity.GetUserId();  <---- here
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
```

---

Please help out. Thank you.

Comment: In the debugger, what is returned and stored in `result`? Is that what you are expecting or not?

Comment: In that case, I suggest making sure whatever `loginInfo` is what you'd expect as well, check that through the debugger, you may have to back track until you find the source of the error. Otherwise I think you'd get the default case on switch

Comment: Thank you JK. I found the answer via the post below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439275/asp-net-identity-user-identity-getuserid-is-always-null-and-user-identity-is

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I resolved my issue:

```
           case SignInStatus.Success:
                ApplicationUser userid = UserManager.FindByEmail(loginInfo.Email);
                string UserId = userid.Id;
```